# Firebase Security rules for admin to write and read everything in database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

i am trying to allow my self to be able to read and write everything in the database.

i am getting a read denied error when trying to run this in the firebase simulator.

```
{
  "rules": {

    ".read": "root.child('Admin').child('isAdmin').child('+$AUID').val() === true",

    "Admin": {
      "isAdmin": {
        "$AUID": {

          ".read": "$AUID === auth.uid",
          ".write": "$AUID === auth.uid",
          ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['active'])",

          "active": {

            "active": "true"
          },
        },
      },
    },
}
```

Comment: Change '+$AUID' to $AUID. And... you are examining the key:value pair of $AUID: true which isn't a valid key:value pair, at least in the provided rules. Also, what defines 'yourself' as opposed to any other user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to give a user access to your Firebase whose level of access is determined by the value in another node, something like this may work. (Not tested)

```
users
  uid_0
    is_admin:true  //your uid
  uid_1
    is_admin:false
```

and rules

```
rules
  ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('is_admin').val() == true"
  ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('is_admin').val() == true"
```

Comment: Thank you so much.